# Posterior Probabilities derivation

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have a problem understanding the posterior probabilities and Bayes rule. First of all my book in communications has shown this formula:

$$P(\textbf{s}_{m}|\textbf{y})=\frac{f(\textbf{y}|\textbf{s}_{m})P(\textbf{s}_{m})}{f(\textbf{y})}$$
where $$f(\textbf{y})= \sum_{m=1}^{M}f(\textbf{y}|\textbf{s}_{m})P(\textbf{s}_{m})$$ and $\textbf{y}$ is the received information vector, $\textbf{s}_{m}$ is the transmitted signal vector (out of m possible vectors)

What I do not understand is how is possible to be mixing pdf's with discrete probabilities and on the top of that conditional probabilities. Could anybody give me a slightly more mathematical derivation? Could I say that

$$P(\textbf{y})=\int f(\textbf{y})dy$$ and likewise $$P(\textbf{y}|\textbf{s}_{m})=\int f(\textbf{y}|\textbf{s}_{m})dy$$ then I could end up using the Bayes'rule and my formula above would follow because I can equal what is inside the integral? That is $$P(\textbf{s}_{m}|\textbf{y}) P(\textbf{y})=P(\textbf{y}|\textbf{s}_{m}) P(\textbf{s}_{m}) $$ Thank you

Comment: just to check, are you happy with Bayes rule itself: $P(A|B) = P(B|A)P(A)/P(B)$?

Comment: @TooTone Yes I am fine with that, I just would like to know if my logic is reasonable, or if not how to go from my last line to the first line.

Comment: Presumably $\textbf{y}$ is a particular value the received vector can take out of an uncountably infinite number of possibilities. So $P(\textbf{y}|\textbf{s}_{m})$ and $P(\textbf{y})=0$

Comment: @Henry : Yes if M tends to infinity, but in this particular situation it is bounded by M which could be a large or small number. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Your question reads as if $\textbf{s}_{m}$ is a discrete random variable (perhaps a finite length meassage using a finite alphabet) while $\textbf{y}$ is a continuous random variable

Comment: @Henry:  Maybe you are correct. Then that is why he had to express Bayes Rule with pdf's rather than $ P(\textbf{y}) or P(\textbf{y}|\textbf{s}_{m})$ which are discrete and amounts to zero? I tried to understand it based on coming from last line to first equation, but last line does not make any sense... That is why I wrote those integrals and wanted to know if they make sense... What do you think?